# Using C++ Library in Linux (eclipse)

Tags: c++, c, linux

I wrote a library and want to test it. I wrote the following program, but I get an error message from eclipse.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    void *handle;
    double (*desk)(char*);
    char *error;

    handle = dlopen ("/lib/CEDD_LIB.so.6", RTLD_LAZY);
    if (!handle) {
        fputs (dlerror(), stderr);
        exit(1);
    }

    desk= dlsym(handle, "Apply"); // ERROR: cannot convert from 'void *' to 'double*(*)(char*)' for argument 1
    if ((error = dlerror()) != NULL)  {
        fputs(error, stderr);
        exit(1);
    }

    dlclose(handle);
}
```

What is wrong?

Regards.

Comment: If this is C++, why does it look so much like C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++ you need the following:

```
typedef double (*func)(char*);
func desk = reinterpret_cast<func>( dlsym(handle, "Apply"));
```

Comment: Yep, html ate my angle brackets :) Fixed, thatnks.

Comment: Now I get this exeption: undefined reference to 'dlerror' ...'dlsqm' ... 'dlclose' Do you know a solution? Spasibo!

Comment: I said this below, but I'll add it here too:
 Are you linking in dl? Try adding '-ldl' the the compiler cmdline.

Answer (score 2):

You need to explicitly cast the return value of dlsym(), it returns a void* and desk is not of type void*. Like this:

`desk = (double (*)(char*))dlsym(handle, "some_function");`

Comment: Huh, I didn't think about it. I explicitly cast as much as I can, I don't like the hidden fun of implicit casts. I'll remove the ding about C vs. c++.

Comment: This might compile in a C compiler though, right? A C++ compiler will require the cast. Or am I wrong?

Comment: (sorry -- deleted comment and then re-added -- confusing)

Comment: In this case it's generally nice to have a typedef for your function pointer so you can cast it without your code line looking like a mess of parens and asterisks.

Comment: Now I get this exeption:
undefined reference to 'dlerror' ...'dlsqm' ... 'dlclose'
Do you know a solution?

Comment: Are you linking in dl? Try adding '-ldl' the the compiler cmdline.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to apply a cast to the return value of dlsym when assigning it to desk. In [this article](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlsym.html), they cast the void* return to their function pointer.

Look at [this article](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlsym.html).